# Force arm64 gcc use instruction to construct double floating point number, no .rodata section

Tags: assembly, gcc, floating-point, arm64, immediate-operand

ARM64 instructions are 32-bit long, so normally a data section is used to store literals if one wants to use a 64-bit floating point constant number.

However, I found in some cases where AArch64 gcc compiler uses several instructions to construct a double floating point number from immediates instead of storing the constant in data section. Is there a way to force this feature?

I do not want to introduce data section in my embedded code.

```
000000000044fda0 <foo>: 1.1, 2.2
  44fda0:       d2800000        mov     x0, #0x0                        // #0
  44fda4:       b0000002        adrp    x2, 450000 <pmalloc+0x78>       // cal data address
  44fda8:       b0000001        adrp    x1, 450000 <pmalloc+0x78>
  44fdac:       fd472c41        ldr     d1, [x2, #3672]                 // load the double
  44fdb0:       fd473020        ldr     d0, [x1, #3680]
  44fdb4:       6d000001        stp     d1, d0, [x0]
  ...
  44fdbc:       d65f03c0        ret


000000000044fda0 <foo>: 5.5, 6.6
  44fda0:       d2800000        mov     x0, #0x0                        // #0
  44fda4:       b203e7e1        mov     x1, #0x6666666666666666         // #7378697629483820646
  44fda8:       1e62d001        fmov    d1, #5.500000000000000000e+00
  44fdac:       f2e80341        movk    x1, #0x401a, lsl #48
  44fdb0:       9e670020        fmov    d0, x1
  44fdb4:       6d000001        stp     d1, d0, [x0]
  ...
  44fdbc:       d65f03c0        ret
```

I want gcc to not use any data section for constructing the double floating literal or integral literal like the second `foo` function I showed.

I am with the following gcc compiler

```
$ aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc --version
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

My C code is `float.c`

```
void foo(void* base_ptr)
{
    double buffer[2]= {5.5, 6.6};
    double* q = (double*)base_ptr;
    *q++ = buffer[0];
    *q = buffer[1];
    return ;
}

int main() {
    double f[2];
    foo(f);
}
```

For `{5.5, 6.6}`, the compiler will construct the literal by shift and bit or instructions. However, when you change `{5.5, 6.6}` to `{1.1, 2.2}`, the compiler will store the constant literals in a data section and use `adrp` instruction to load the address and fetch them.

for `{5.5, 6.6}`

```
$ aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc float.c
$ aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -d a.out  | grep -A15 '<foo>:'
00000000000007b4 <foo>:
 7b4:   a9bc7bfd        stp     x29, x30, [sp, #-64]!
 7b8:   910003fd        mov     x29, sp
 7bc:   f9000fa0        str     x0, [x29, #24]
 7c0:   90000080        adrp    x0, 10000 <__FRAME_END__+0xf6d8>
 7c4:   f947f000        ldr     x0, [x0, #4064]
 7c8:   f9400001        ldr     x1, [x0]
 7cc:   f9001fa1        str     x1, [x29, #56]
 7d0:   d2800001        mov     x1, #0x0                        // #0
 7d4:   1e62d000        fmov    d0, #5.500000000000000000e+00
 7d8:   fd0017a0        str     d0, [x29, #40]
 7dc:   b203e7e0        mov     x0, #0x6666666666666666         // #7378697629483820646
 7e0:   f2e80340        movk    x0, #0x401a, lsl #48
 7e4:   9e670000        fmov    d0, x0
 7e8:   fd001ba0        str     d0, [x29, #48]
 7ec:   f9400fa0        ldr     x0, [x29, #24]
```

for `{1.1, 2.2}`

```
$ aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -d a.out  | grep -A15 '<foo>:'
00000000000007b4 <foo>:
 7b4:   a9bc7bfd        stp     x29, x30, [sp, #-64]!
 7b8:   910003fd        mov     x29, sp
 7bc:   f9000fa0        str     x0, [x29, #24]
 7c0:   90000080        adrp    x0, 10000 <__FRAME_END__+0xf6b8>
 7c4:   f947f000        ldr     x0, [x0, #4064]
 7c8:   f9400001        ldr     x1, [x0]
 7cc:   f9001fa1        str     x1, [x29, #56]
 7d0:   d2800001        mov     x1, #0x0                        // #0
 7d4:   90000000        adrp    x0, 0 <_init-0x620>
 7d8:   9124e000        add     x0, x0, #0x938
 7dc:   fd400000        ldr     d0, [x0]
 7e0:   fd0017a0        str     d0, [x29, #40]
 7e4:   90000000        adrp    x0, 0 <_init-0x620>
 7e8:   91250000        add     x0, x0, #0x940
 7ec:   fd400000        ldr     d0, [x0]
```

It's a really strange feature. I want a compiler option to switch this on and off.

Comment: Can you post the corresponding C code?

Comment: You might be able to supply `-mpc-relative-literal-loads` to have gcc use a literal pool next to your code instead of going through the data section.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why the data section cannot be used?  This seems like a weird requirement.  You won't get very far without a data section.

Comment: Constants will go in `.rodata`, which you can link as part of the same program segment as code since it's also read-only.  (Modern `ld` will put them in different segments to minimize Spectre / ROP gadgets, at least on x86 where finding data that works as machine code is more common.)

Comment: For double-precision constants that only require the most significant 8 bits of the mantissa, compilers can use `fmov` with literal. For DP constants with a byte-wise repeating mantissa pattern, compilers can use the `mov`, `movk`, `fmov` sequence. Arbitrary DP constants will require even longer instruction sequences. Would that still be beneficial, and if so, why? Can you change the constants in your code so one of the two existing optimizations apply?

Comment: I elaborate a bit and add my C code.

Comment: Keep in mind that moves between general-purpose and FP/SIMD registers are rather expensive on many ARM64 CPUs.  `fmov dn, xm` is 5 cycles latency on Cortex A-72.

Answer (score 1):

The option you want is called `-mslow-flash-data` but the manual for my gcc version at least says this is only supported for ARMv7M architecture.